# Can you Measure TCP bandwidth, latency and jitter with Netty?

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I'm currently writing a Minecraft client emulator in Java for a final year E&E engineering project. I'm using this [library](https://github.com/Steveice10/PacketLib) to handle the packets. The library internally uses the Netty 5.0 library for networking.

Part of my project involves measuring bandwidth, latency and jitter of the packets being sent. Bandwidth isn't so much of a problem since I know which packets are being sent/received but I don't know how to measure the latency and jitter.

To my knowledge TCP packets do contain timing information. Is there anyway to access this information or directly measure latency/jitter through Netty?

Comment: I understand the latency or jitter you need to have timing at the start and the end.  This is something you either need to add or you need to record the packets and analyse these separately.

Comment: For the purposes of my project having the time a packet was sent (even if its only comparable to other packets) is sufficient. We consider latency as the time between being sent and being received and jitter to be the change in packet "time spacing" (if two packets are sent 5ms apart and arrive 3ms apart the jitter is considered to be 2ms).

Comment: Ok you can do this, the only problem is that you can't access a timestamp in the TCP header.  Instead you need to look at either adding the timestamp to the message or record this information somewhere else.  Note: if you are looking at long latencies like milli-seconds your main cause will be GC pauses, you may find that recording these pause might be a good start.

Comment: Note: if you need to record micro-second pauses and jitter you will need to much more careful about how you record your data.

Comment: Adding the information myself is my last resort. I would have to change a lot of code I didn't write both client-side and server-side. I'm asking this question specifically to make sure I don't reinvent the wheel. I come from an engineering background, not computer science, so the simpler the solution the better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to measure request/response time.  Your client sends a message which has a expected response from the server.  You can then use tcpdump or wireshark to record all the packets and write a tool to calculate the request to response time.

This can be done without changing the code of the client or server.